# Google Sheets' Column Lock

Tags: google-sheets

Does anyone know how to lock a column in Google Sheets without affecting other columns if there are any structural changes in the sheet. For example, I'm trying to lock one column, but when I try to remove any filters and changing the column size, it is showing a warning pop up that protection is being applied to one of the columns in this sheet.

Please let me know anyone how to solve this problem?

Comment: I don't think it's possible, if you delete a row it necessarily alters a protected cell. Nothing you can do about it

Comment: If you are still looking for help on this please clarify what you mean by "column lock" as this term in not something that is included in https://support.google.com/docs

Answer (score -1):

- you can either **Protect range...** of column:

  [image: 0]

---

- or **Freeze** column:

  [image: 0]

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply. I really appreciate. 

But I know how to apply protection in any column. What's the issue the I'm facing is that when I am trying to apply protection in one of the column and makes any changes in the sheet like removing filters and resizing columns then it is asking to remove the protection first although I am not making any changes in that column but it is affecting whole sheet.

I just want to know how to protect column so that it should not disturb other columns in the sheet when making changes to part of the sheet?

Comment: @RohitGupta can you share a copy/dummy of your sheet for debugging?